# display same text on screen without flipping the screen with other shapes/images using PsychToolBox MATLAB

Tags: matlab, screen, psychtoolbox

Is there a way to have a certain text/shape/image stays on the screen in front of other objects without flipping with the rest of objects on and off the screen? For example, I want to have a fixation crosshair always stays on the screen without changing with the images behind it.

In another word, can "Screen('Flip',window)" only flip certain shapes but not all that are on the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate that the frame shouldn't be cleared after a Flip, by setting the don't clear Flag to 1:

```
Screen('Flip', wPtr, [], 1);
```

However, with this you can overlay new objects on the frame, but if you want to remove any of them, you have to remove them all - the next call to clip without the don't clear flag set to 1 will clear everything:

```
try
    screenNum= max(Screen('Screens'));
    Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 1);
    [wPtr, wRect]=Screen('OpenWindow', screenNum, 0);

    % draw fixation, indicate that the frame buffer should not be cleared
    DrawFormattedText(wPtr, '+', 'center', 'center', 255);
    Screen('Flip', wPtr, [], 1);
    WaitSecs(1);

    % overlay a purple oval, in addition to the fixation
    Screen('FillOval', wPtr, [128 0 128], [0 0 100 100])
    Screen('Flip', wPtr, []);
    WaitSecs(1);

    % display an orange oval, this will be presented without the fixation
    % unless the previous purple oval is also retained
    Screen('FillOval', wPtr, [128 128 0], [100 100 200 200])
    Screen('Flip', wPtr, []);
    WaitSecs(1);

    sca;

catch e
    sca;
   rethrow(e) 
end
```

If you need to frequently draw the fixation cross, with other objects being added and removed, another option is to store the fixation as a texture, which can be more easily redrawn on every frame.